# Bootstrap listgroup in modal doesn't display content with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working on a project and now have some problem!!

I build a site basically generate content though javascript.
Here is my project site: http://www.makinoworks.com/makinogames/kancolle/

I use [jQuery]+[MixItUp]+[papaparse] to generate content sort in some rules
And also use [BootStrap] to show up Modal/ListGroup etc..

But when website finished, it doesn't display content.
[image: modal]
[image: code]

It's strange that HTML current written but nothing display.
Thanks for helping.
If need any more information please tell me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a font-size to the class `.list-group-item` or `.list-group-item span`

```
.list-group-item {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    margin-bottom: -1px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    font-size: 10pt;
}
```